# LNK2019: unresolved error in singletone

Tags: c++, qt, lnk2019

i need help to figure out what wrong about that code:

```
class DatabaseEngine
{
protected:
    DatabaseEngine();
    static DatabaseEngine* m_DatabaseEngine;
public:
    static DatabaseEngine& instance();
    void do_something();
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "databaseengine.h"

DatabaseEngine* DatabaseEngine::m_DatabaseEngine=nullptr;

DatabaseEngine::DatabaseEngine()
{
}


static DatabaseEngine& DatabaseEngine:: instance()
{
    if(m_DatabaseEngine==nullptr)
{
    m_DatabaseEngine=new DatabaseEngine;`enter code here`
}
return *m_DatabaseEngine;
}

void DatabaseEngine::do_something()
{

}
```

userwindow.cpp:

```
#include "databaseengine.h"
UsersWindow::UsersWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::UsersWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    DatabaseEngine::instance().do_something();
}

UsersWindow::~UsersWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

userswindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class DatabaseEngine & __cdecl DatabaseEngine::instance(void)" (?instance@DatabaseEngine@@SAAAV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall UsersWindow::UsersWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0UsersWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)

userswindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall DatabaseEngine::do_something(void)" (?do_something@DatabaseEngine@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall UsersWindow::UsersWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0UsersWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)

thanks

Comment: To me it looks like the cpp file for DatabaseEngine is not included in the project so Visual Studio is not compiling that code.

Comment: BTW, One of the reasons I thought this was the error that both answers are mentioning. I saw that your .cpp file could not compile. So if you got no errors about that you either posted the wrong code or the file was not part of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `static` keyword from your static function definition:

Wrong:

```
static DatabaseEngine& DatabaseEngine::instance()
```

Correct:

```
DatabaseEngine& DatabaseEngine::instance()
```

Answer (score 0):

declaration:

```
static DatabaseEngine& DatabaseEngine::instance();
   ^
only in declaration
```

definition:

```
DatabaseEngine& DatabaseEngine:: instance() {
   // code here
}
```

also make sure DatabaseEngine.cpp file is included in your project and is being compiled

Answer (score 0):

You can use static variable in the static method instance to hold the unique instance and return the pointer. This is also a smart advice from Effective C++ I think. The example is untested but it should work

```
class DatabaseEngine
{
public:
    static DatabaseEngine& instance(){
        static DatabaseEngine db;
        return db;
    }
};
```